# Angular unit testing controller $scope length

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I'm trying to test a controller with a service that gets some data with $http,

storesController.js

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('storesController', ['storesService']);

    app.controller('StoresListController', function ($scope, StoresService) {

        $scope.getStores = function () {
            StoresService.getStores().then(function (data) {
                $scope.stores = data.data;
            });
        };
        $scope.getStores();

        $scope.deleteStore = function (id) {
            StoresService.deleteStore(id).then(function () {
                $scope.getStores();
            });

        };
    });
})()
```

storesService.js

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('storesService', []);

    app.factory('StoresService', ['$http','appConfig', function ($http,appConfig) {

            var webServiceUrl = appConfig.webServiceUrl;
            var stores = [];

            stores.getStores = function () {
               return $http.get(webServiceUrl + 'getStores');
            };            
            return stores;

        }]);

})();
```

and my test

```
describe("Store Controller", function () {
var StoresService, createController, scope;

beforeEach(function () {
    module('storesController');
    module(function ($provide) {
        $provide.value('StoresService', {
            getStores: function () {
                return {
                    then: function (callback) {
                        return callback([
                            {name: "testName", country: "testCountry"},
                            {name: "testName2", country: "testCountry2"},
                            {name: "testName3", country: "testCountry3"},
                        ]);
                    }
                };
            },
        });
        return null;
    });
});

beforeEach(function () {
    inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, _StoresService_) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        StoresService = _StoresService_;
        createController = function () {
            return $controller("StoresListController", {
                $scope: scope,
            });
        };
    });
});

it("should call the store service to retrieve the store list", function () {
    createController();
    expect(scope.stores.length).toBe(3);
});
```

});

I'm trying to test that when the controller is created the method $scope.getStores() is called and the variable $scope.stores is an object with a length of 3. I've try several ways to test it but I'm  not being able to make it work, getting this error

```
TypeError: scope.stores is undefined
```

Maybe I should go into a different approach with $httpBackend, I'm starting with unit testing and I'm a bit lost, Can somebody give a hand?

Comment: $http get requests are asynchronous, so it is likely that the request is working correctly, but when your test runs the result of the request is not resolved. $scope.$apply() might help but I haven't had to write unit tests for angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this will make the code work:

```
return callback({ data: [
                            {name: "testName", country: "testCountry"},
                            {name: "testName2", country: "testCountry2"},
                            {name: "testName3", country: "testCountry3"},
                        ]});
```

But I think actually creating a fake promise is more readable and less error prone - something like this:

```
describe("Store Controller", function () {
    var StoresService, createController, scope, $q;

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('storesController');
        module(function ($provide) {
            $provide.value('StoresService', {
                getStores: function () {},
            });
            return null;
        });
    });

    beforeEach(function () {
        inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, _StoresService_, _$q_) {
            $q = _$q_;
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            StoresService = _StoresService_;
            createController = function () {
                return $controller("StoresListController", {
                    $scope: scope,
                });
            };
        });
    });

    it("should call the store service to retrieve the store list", function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        // Return fake promise.
        spyOn(StoresService, 'getStores').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);

        createController();
        // Resolve fake promise with some data.
        deferred.resolve({ data: 'some data'});
        // Callback from promise wont execute without digest:
        $rootScope.$digest();

        expect(scope.stores).toEqual('some data');
    });
    });
```